# Finite Number of Turing Machines that stop after k steps?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, turing-completeness

For this question suppose Alphabet for input is {0,1}.

Given:

```
L={<M> | M stops on every input after maximum 1000 steps}
```

My professor claimed that there is a finite **different** Turing machines (M) in L, But why is that?

One of the students mentioned something about finite number of snapshots (1001) But I don't agree or understand.

A snapshot contains q, current state which can be thousands of options. the same for the content...

Comment: $L$ is an infinite language. Just add redundant states to any existing TM, and you get an infinite number of different TMs which all do the same thing, and hence also are in $L$.

Comment: L is decidable, you don't really need to worry about every input, only about a finite subset. Maybe that's what your teacher is talking about.

Comment: @nirshahar Sorry I meant finite Different Turing machines.